# Change asp.net mvc application name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This should be the easiest thing to do however I simply can't figure it out. How do I change the name of my asp.net mvc application? I want to call it "Middly" instead of "Application Name".

My project and namespace are already called "Middly". Kindly provide an easy way of doing this as I am at beginner level. Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing "Application Name" that you want to change it?

Comment: you want to rename your project name "Middly" to "Application Name" or something else let me know clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the */Views/Shared* folder in **Solution Explorer** and open the **_Layout.cshtml** file. This file is called a layout page and it's in the shared folder that all other pages use.
2. Change the contents of the title element. Change the ActionLink in the
   layout template from "Application name" to "Middly"

Refer below link if you are having problem doing this:
[Adding a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view)

Answer (score 2):

it appears to be simply hard coded text

@Html.ActionLink("Application name",...

Answer (score 1):

You can open the .sln and .csproj files in a text editor such as Notepad++ and update all references from 'Application Name' to 'Middly'

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer, click on Site.Master. Look for the class "navbar-brand", you should see the application name and change it.